# Custom naming conventions in visual studio code analysis?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, lint

Can I setup my own naming conventions in VS code analysis?

For example:

```
m_VarName;
VarName;
varName;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be possible in Visual Studio 15.

> We've also added/updated style analyzers to help you customize and
>   enforce coding conventions on your team, including:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs15-relnotes#debuggingdiag

Answer (score -1):

Should be able to. Though I don't see why you don't just type them as you go, no needed to really set up a name convention in VS :)